# Popular um spinner com dados armazenados em um nó no Firebase para Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estou realizando um serviço para um cliente onde preciso popular um `Spinner` com dados armazenados em um nó no Firebase. Já tentei diversos tutoriais, porém não obtive resultado.

Eu criei duas entidades em meu projeto, uma entidade `Clientes`, que contém os atributos e `getters` e `setters` de `clientes` e outra entidade chamada `Prefixos`, que contém também atributos e `getters` e `setters` de prefixos de carros.

Criei duas `activity's`, uma para cadastrar novos clientes e outra para cadastrar novos prefixos. Os clientes e prefixos estão sendo cadastrados corretamente em nós no Firebase, porém, quando tento pegar os dados cadastrados nos nós `Clientes` e `Prefixos` para colocar em um `Spinner`, não estou conseguindo populá-lo corretamente em uma `activity` que contém estes `spinners`.

Para sumarizar: tenho uma `activity` separada das `activitys` de cadastro, onde tenho um `spinner` para `cliente` e um para `prefixo`, onde quero mostrar em um `spinner` o nome do cliente e o prefixo do carro dele, mas não estou obtendo êxito. Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Onde está o código problemático?

Answer (score 1):

@Brian Moreira eu tive o mesmo problema para popular o spinner, porem consegui fazendo este código espero que te ajude.

```
 reference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String areaName = areaSnapshot.child("localRestaurante").getValue(String.class);
                        if (areaName == local) {
                            String nomerestaurante = areaSnapshot.child("nome").getValue(String.class);
                            areas.add(nomerestaurante);

                        } else {
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    SpinnerPratos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_pratos);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areas);
                    areasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    SpinnerPratos.setAdapter(areasAdapter);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
```

Obs.: Vi que você postou sua pergunta a três dias e ninguém te respondeu sugiro que na próxima pergunta quer fizer, coloque o código que você esta utilizando pois, a comunidade acha que você nem tentou e ta aqui para receber uma resposta pronta ai o pessoal não te responde.